# Return sum of sublist in a list

Tags: f#

I've been trying to figure this out for the last few hours with no success what so ever.

Let's say I have a list of lists of int

```
let list = [[1;3;4;4];[1;3]]
```

I have to create a function that will sum the sublists and return one list as below:

```
[12;4]
```

I've been told that I should use List.fold.

I've tried the following:

```
let list = [2;3;5]
let sumList list = List.fold (fun acc elem -> acc + elem) 0 list
sumList list
```

this is returning only an int and works only for an int list and not for a list of list. What are the next steps from here.

Comment: List.map is the next hint

Comment: Sorry if I'm dumb. I'm very new at functional programming.
I looked at the the documentation for List.map and I understood that it applies a given function to each element.

I tried to do this :
 `let sumLists list = List.map (fun x -> List.fold (fun acc elem -> acc + elem) 0 list) `

which is obviously not working

Comment: First, write a function then sums a list.  Then write a new function with list.map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
list 
|> List.map List.sum
```

So you map the List.sum for each element in the list.

Or with fold:

```
list 
|> List.map (List.fold (+) 0)
```

`(List.fold (+) 0)` is the same as the sum function. It starts with zero and adds in each iteration the value to the accumulator.

```
list 
|> List.fold (fun acc v -> 
    acc @ [(List.fold (+) 0) v]) []
```

As you see, you can also replace the map with a fold.

```
list 
|> List.foldBack (fun v acc -> 
    (List.fold (+) 0 v) :: acc) 
    <| []
```

With `List.foldBack` it looks a little bit better in my opinion than with fold.  But I prefer the first solution.

Comment: And don't forget `(list, []) ||> List.foldBack (fun v acc -> (List.fold (+) 0 v)::acc)`, which I find more readable than the last solution (using `<|`).